# Mod_rewrite and URL redirection - APACHE,Mod_rewrite,PHP,Codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have got a very specific problem. I am using wamp server to run my codeigniter projects locally. I have loaded mod_rewrite in and it is showing in my phpinfo.

In my wamp root directory, I have a codeigniter project folder "mysite".Here is the directory structure of mysite.

```
-mysite
   |--images
   |--eshots
   |--useruploads
   |--temp
   |--SpryAssets
   |--css
   |--js
   |--timthumb
```

After enabling this mod_rewrite, I modified my "host" file in my windows directory and added this line of code in my virtual host file to access my website like this. (mysite.local)

```
   127.0.0.1 mysite.local
```

After this I created an htaccess file in root directory (i.e under mysite folder)

```
  htaccess file:

  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond $1  !^(index\.php|images|lists|eshots|useruploads|temp|SpryAssets|css|js|robots\.txt|timthumb\.php)

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]

  <IfModule mod_security.c>

  SecFilterEngine Off

  SecFilterScanPOST Off

  </IfModule>
```

After this, when I try to access my website from the wamp, it leads me to nowhere. For example, if I click from localhost's project folder i.e mysite, it takes me back to the localhost folder and my URL looks like this:

http://mysite.local/mysite/

and when I click on mysite again, it shows the URL like this:

http://mysite.local/mysite/mysite

And after this, my link doesn't take me to the web pages. And remain stuck here.
Why am I getting this behavior from server? Is there any problem with CODEIGNITER or htaccess file that is stopping this? And what steps I need to do so that I could get each N everything working including javascript, css, images .

**How to deal with this challenging problem?**
Mostly people say you need to have your mod_rewrite enabled or read manual provided from Apache.

[UPDATED]:
when I TRIED WID new codeigniter project.FIRST,I copied all the files apart from htaccess file into project folder.Luckily i was able to navigate to the index page but it didnt show me any css,image,scripts.
My htaccess consists of only these bits:            RewriteEngine on    .

What shall i do now to make my js,images work as above?Apache_error log looks like this:.Also,when i try to move onto next pages ,it says "(Error:404)The requested URL /Code/wham.local/categories/listings/Products  was not found".Kindly suggest.Where wham.local is virtual host.

**apache_error Log:**

```
 [Sun Nov 25 13:00:54 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: D:/wamp/www/css, referer: http://localhost/Code/
 [Sun Nov 25 13:00:54 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: D:/wamp/www/css, referer: http://localhost/Code/
 [Sun Nov 25 13:00:54 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: D:/wamp/www/js, referer: http://localhost/Code/
 [Sun Nov 25 13:00:54 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: D:/wamp/www/js, referer: http://localhost/Code/
 [Sun Nov 25 13:00:54 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: D:/wamp/www/js, referer: http://localhost/Code/
 [Sun Nov 25 13:00:54 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: D:/wamp/www/js, referer: http://localhost/Code/

 [Sun Nov 25 13:00:54 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: D:/wamp/www/js, referer: http://localhost/Code/

 [Sun Nov 25 13:00:54 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: D:/wamp/www/images, referer: http://localhost/Code/
 [Sun Nov 25 13:00:54 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: D:/wamp/www/images, referer: http://localhost/Code/
 [Sun Nov 25 13:00:54 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: D:/wamp/www/images, referer: http://localhost/Code/
 [Sun Nov 25 13:00:54 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: D:/wamp/www/images, referer: http://localhost/Code/
 [Sun Nov 25 13:00:54 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: D:/wamp/www/images, referer: http://localhost/Code/
 [Sun Nov 25 13:00:54 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: D:/wamp/www/images, referer: http://localhost/Code/
 [Sun Nov 25 13:00:54 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: D:/wamp/www/images
 [Sun Nov 25 13:01:03 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: D:/wamp/www/images
 [Sun Nov 25 13:01:55 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: D:/wamp/www/images
 [Sun Nov 25 13:01:56 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: D:/wamp/www/Code/wham.local, referer: http://localhost/Code/
```

Comment: I assume because you were able to click anything that you updated your vhosts file. Dumb question, but how are you constructing your links? href="mysite" vs href="/mysite" vs href="<?php echo site_url('mysite')" etc

Comment: Sorry, I had a response but I realized it was overlooking something you said. To answer your question about my CI installation and setup, I did nothing special. I placed CI in a direcory, added the IP localhost to the hosts file, updated the httpd-hosts file like mohan said, restarted wampp and it was working.

Comment: @KaiQing my images ,css and js not working.And also,i have included the apache_error log .could you please have a look at it and suggest why url is not formatting in an appropriate way??i would appreciate if you could do so.thanks

Comment: @KaiQing my cofig file consits of these enteries now:  $config['base_url'] = "wham.local";  
$config['domain_name'] = 'wham.local';

Comment: @KaiQing if i send you my project in email,could you be able to have a look at configurations??I am desperately looking for a solution.Help me please

Answer (score 2):

check the http.conf file in C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\conf 
if their is entry like this 
        #Virtual hosts
        #Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
        then open the file httpd-vhosts.conf add below lines  in it.

```
     <VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot  "C:/wamp/www/mysite/"
       ServerName     mysite.local
      </VirtualHost>

     <VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot  "C:/wamp/www/"
      ServerName     localhost
      </VirtualHost>
```

otherwise you can add this line to httpd.conf file also 
and restart ur server. 
this is the virtual host concept.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this line is messing with you:

```
RewriteCond $1  !^(index\.php|images|lists|eshots|useruploads|temp|SpryAssets|css|js|robots\.txt|timthumb\.php)
```

Try this instead

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^(index\.php|images|lists|eshots|useruploads|temp|SpryAssets|css|js|robots\.txt|timthumb\.php)
```

Comment: I think his htaccess is default CI. It's almost identical to the ones I use locally

Comment: @Joshua Kaiser i tried the way you suggested me above.But problem still there.Is there anything missing from above steps??i mean is this something to do with apache httpd.config file and creating virtual host??Sorry.i am not getting any clue where things are going wrong.

Comment: @KaiQing i am constructing url in Codeigniter like this : http://mysite.local/contactus        ,  http://mysite.local/aboutus  , http://mysite.local/section/edit/1   etc. I would appreciate if you could you tell me what steps you have done to make your code igniter project work on your localhost ??

Comment: @BilalKhalid I'm sorry that wasn't more help.  What's going on in your apache log?

Comment: @JoshuaKaiser Thanks.I TRIED WID new codeigniter project.FIRST,I copied all the files apart from htaccess file into project folder.Luckily i was able to navigate to the index page but it didnt show me any css,image,scripts.My htaccess consists of only these bits:            RewriteEngine on    .What shall i do now to make my js,images work as above?Apache_error log looks like this:(SEE above EDITED QUESTION details).Also,when i try to move onto next pages ,it says "(Error:404)The requested URL /Code/wham.local/categories/listings/Products  was not found".Kindly sugggest

Comment: @JoshuaKaiser  and my codeigiter config file consists of these enteries :  $config['base_url'] = "wham.local";  
$config['domain_name'] = 'wham.local';

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable rewrite module for apache.. you can do this by going to 
`wamp tray icon` > `apache` > `apache module` then select `rewrite module`.