# How to link external php pages with code igniter projects?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an external photo library in the root of my code igniter project that I used for my non MVC framework projects in the past.I want to use embed that library to my new code igniter project.How can I achieve this as my php photo library is not MVC based? I mean in external folder folder, it works fine when I access the index.php with my ip address like this:

```
  http://10.0.0.27/myproject/mylibrary/
```

But when i try to access the library using this :

```
  http://myproject.new/mylibrary/
```

it gives me error 404" Page not found" which I can assume is due to non MVC pattern of that photo library.How can i solve this issue?is there anyway i can access my library like this??? ie.

```
  http://myproject.new/mylibrary/
```

Comment: you need to change the format of te path. use absolute url. Put the library in the `library` folder under `applcation` and initiate it. wthout seeing any code, this is far as i can advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't have `index.php` in your URL, you probably have something like this in your htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

The above rewrites everything except images and robots.txt to your index.php, so you can modify that to exclude `mylibrary` as well:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|mylibrary|robots\.txt)
```

Comment: @MrCode.Cheers.This one worked for me.I appreciate your help.Ta

Comment: @MrCode.Kinfly help me with this.I am stuck with this for more than 3 weeks but noone could help.Plz guide me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537003/mod-rewite-and-url-redirection-apache-mod-rewrite-php-codeigniter/13537167#13537167

Answer (score 1):

I assume (based on your url) you are rewriting the urls

If you're using the [default codeigniter based url rewriting patterns](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html) you can add the `/mylibrary/` folder to the list of excluded items

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|mylibrary|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Now you should be able to directly access that folder

Comment: @Dale.Cheers.This one worked for me.I appreciate your help.Ta

Comment: @Dale.I think this is something to do with .htaccess.I would appreciate if you could help me this challenging issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537003/mod-rewite-and-url-redirection-apache-mod-rewrite-php-codeigniter/13537167#13537167

Comment: @BilalKhalid I think mohat's answer should help you there champ